# Examples of Lp spaces in Applied Math

Tags: soft-question, intuition, lp-spaces, applications

I was wondering if there are examples of exotic Lp spaces being used in applied mathematics.

I know that the "special" p's (1,2 , infinity ) are of use, for example in statistics, L1 is mean, L2 is standard deviation and L infinity is maximum deviation.

Are there any applied areas that use exotic p's or hopefully all of the p's to represent something?

Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843108/why-are-lp-spaces-so-ubiquitous and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28147/why-do-we-care-about-lp-spaces-besides-p-1-p-2-and-p-infinity