# Where does the $L^p$ norm come from?

Tags: functional-analysis, moment-problem

Where exactly do $L^p$ norms and $L^p$ spaces show up *naturally*? In other words, how would you arrive at these concepts out of necessity of solving some other problem in a way that motivates using them?

My attempt: [Bernkopf's history](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41133253?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) points out that they first arose as part of the [moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem):

[image]

Kline's Mathematical Thought III says that Riesz was "obliged" to introduce these ideas because he (randomly???!) used Holder and Minkowski's inequalities:

[image]

So, taking a simple case as though you were living in 1910 trying to invent functional analysis:

Given a function (a random variable, but thinking heuristically here) $g(x)$ with Taylor (orthogonal) expansion

$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n g_n(x)$$

and a probability distribution $f(x)$ we know the expected value of $f$ over $I = [0,1]$ is
$$\int_I g(x)f(x)dx = \int_I \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n f(x) dx = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_n \int_I x^n f(x) dx = \sum_{i=0}^\infty c_n a_n$$

I can see the necessity, if you want to invert this process (i.e. for a given $g_p(x) = x^p$, finding a probability distribution $f$ such that $\int x^p f(x)dx = a_p$), of defining an $L^p$ space as [the space of all](http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~moulib/stat612-notes-0.pdf) functions $h$ whose $p$'th power is integrable with respect to the density $f(x)$:
$$L^p = \{ h | \int |h(x)|^p f(x) dx < \infty \}$$
so that for our example $h(x) = x \in L^p$ gives $\int_I x^p f(x) dx < \infty$, but since we will also have $\int_I x^n f(x)dx = \int_I g_n(x) f(x)dx$ terms we also want to have $\int_I g_n(x)^p f(x)dx < \infty$.

*But I **can't*** see why, from this, you'd define the $L^p$ norm of $x$ to be

$$||x|| = ( \int_I x^p f(x) dx)^{1/p} $$

or how this gives "[the $p$'th moments of a random variable](https://mathoverflow.net/a/28179/38721)" when what I did above gives them? What is the point of those complicated roots? In other words I don't see why you'd think to invoke Holder or Minkowski from thin air.

**My guess** is that you would only do this because you knew in advance you would need to bound the integral $\int_I g(x) f(x)dx$ as part of proving some $f$ existed, so you just wanted *any* inequality you could find, and Holder/Minkowski were just the ones Riesz just knew of?

Can anybody clean this up or make a better version, preferably indicating why you'd know to apply this material to differential equations too?

Comment: $L^1$ is natural; it describes mass and similar such things. $L^2$ is essentially natural; it generalizes Euclidean space more or less directly, and there are other obvious reasons to use it, such as aspects of PDE and harmonic analysis. $L^\infty$ is natural, we like to talk about uniform distances. I rarely see the others "jump out from the math". One place is in Sobolev embedding of $W^{k,p}$ where $p=1,2$ or $\infty$. Another place is the Berry-Esseen theorem.

Comment: you might find this useful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683399/why-define-norm-in-l-p-in-that-way/1692234#1692234

Comment: Riesz knew about Minkowski and H\"{o}lder inequalities, and he restricted his attention to cases where these applied, which is why he left out $L^1$. The condition $\int |f|^p < \infty$ was a natural generalization from $L^2$. With that he was led to consider $(\int |f|^p)^{1/p}$, and to use these inequalities to show you end up with a norm. It appears that the decision to consider $\int |f|^p < \infty$ led to the use of Minkowski and H\"{o}lder inequalities, and that led to norms. In other words, norms didn't come first, the finite integral conditions did.

Comment: Was just checking to see how much time I have left