# Why are $L^p$ spaces for $p\not=1,2,\infty$ important?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

$L^p$ spaces for arbitrary $1\le p\le\infty$  are a mainstay of basic functional analysis courses, but I've only seen them "in action" when $p$ is 1, 2, or $\infty$. Can anyone give an "elementary" concrete example of an application of another $L^p$ space?

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment on why we don't hear about those "other" $L^p$ spaces nearly as much. First, $L^p$ is a Hilbert space iff $p=2$, this is why $L^2$ gets the most air time. On the other hand, $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ have norms with a straightforward geometric interpretation.

Comment: Right - that's why I'm curious about interpretations for the other ones.

Comment: i think from a theoretical (not necessarily practical!) point of view the spaces have an interest (1) because if $p \lt 1$ local convexity is lost and (2) because of the duality between $L_p$ and $L_q$ when $p$ and $q$ are "Holder conjugates", with $\frac1{p}+\frac1{q}=1$ the self-dual case $p=q=2$ is evidently very special. $L_{\infty}$ and $L_1$ also satisfy the conjugacy relation.

Comment: Not an "application", but they are all Banach spaces. Since $p=2$ is exceptional (noted above), then $p=1,\infty$ have a simple geometry, it seems natural to ask if we can generalize vector $p$ norms to the function space setting and see what properties are preserved. (I admit this is not an "application". Perhaps this would provide "motivation" for studying them.) Finally, the structure of their dual spaces $L^p$ and $L^q$ where $1/p+1/q=1$ is even more motivation.

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810029/what-is-lp-convergence-useful-for/. But note that the linked question goes in another direction. There, the importance of $L^p$ spaces in general is considered, whereas here the question is more about the "unusual" case $p \neq 1,2,\infty$.

Comment: Also, since $\|f\|_{L^\infty}=\lim_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_{L^p}$, the "intermediate" $p$ values become relevant in understanding $L^\infty$.

Comment: Moser's proof of the Harnack inequality is a good example of how $L^p$ spaces are used in (at least elliptic) PDE: To gain more 'regularity' you seek higher integrability (of the function, it's gradient or other quantities).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $L^p$-spaces with $p=1,2,\infty$ get the most attention due to their special properties: $L^2$ is Hilbert, $L^\infty$ and $L^1$ are not reflexive, $L^\infty$ is not separable, $L^1$ has no predual, and so on. Viewed as plain Banach spaces, maybe the spaces $L^p$, $p\not \in\{1,2,\infty\}$ are just boring spaces with no special and interesting properties.

$L^p$-spaces have their uses in Sobolev theory as well: There, functions $u$ with first (weak) derivative are assumed in say $L^p(\Omega)$, the space capturing this is called $W^{1,p}$. In the Sobolev theory, the exponent $p$ has a crucial role. If for instance $p$ is large enough ($p$ larger than space dimension) then the functions in $W^{1,p}$ have a continuous representative. An application of these spaces is the theory of partial differential equations. Here, the value of the exponent $p$ matters to conclude smoothness of function due to Sobolev embedding theorems.

Comment: My impression is that Sobolev theory for $p \neq 2$ often arises in studying _nonlinear_ PDE, whereas the $L^2$ Sobolev theory is usually sufficient for _linear_ problems.

Comment: For a start into linear PDEs, Hilbert spaces $H^1$, $L^2$ are sufficient. Theory is much easier with Hilbert spaces (think Lax-Milgram). $p\ne2$ arises if one asks under which conditions on $f$ the solution to $-\Delta u=f$, $u=0$ on the boundary, is bounded or continuous. Then Hilbert space techniques are not sufficient even for this linear problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there are very few applications of the cases where $p \ne 1,2, \infty$.

One example: in $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$, the balls corresponding to the $l^p$ norms are so-called  [super ellipses](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) and [superquadrics](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superquadrics). These are things that are shaped somewhat like regular ellipses, but with corners that become "sharper" as $p$ increases. These are occasionally used for designing consumer products, sculptures, or the shapes of characters in fonts. But even this is a stretch; you can get roughly the same design freedom with Bézier curves and surfaces, and that's what most people would use, in practice.

I think the only reason that the cases where $p \ne 1,2, \infty$ get mentioned at all is that people can't resist the lure of abstraction; we love to have grand unifying generalizations, rather than separate enumerations of special cases, even if this means weaker results and muddied focus.