# Use cases for $L^p$ and $l^p$ spaces where $p\neq 1,2,\infty$

Tags: metric-spaces, soft-question, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, big-list

Soft question:  $L^1,L^2,$ and $L^\infty$ spaces all have many practical uses and an easy intuition behind them (Along with the $l^1$, etc. versions).  Just for visualization, I was playing around with $l^1(\mathbb{R}^2),l^2(\mathbb{R}^2),  l^p (\mathbb{R}^2), \text{and} l^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2) $ while walking home and considering the distance from (0,0) to (1,1).  Trivially we get the general case of $d_p ((0,0),(1,1))=(2)^\frac 1 p$.  Intuitionally,  I get for $p=1$ we have the taxicab metric,  $p=2$ our Euclidean metric,  and that for $p>q$,  $d_p((0,0),(1,1))<d_q((0,0), (1,1))$
with the limiting behavior being $$\lim_{p\to \infty}d_p((0,0),(1,1))=1=d_\infty ((0,0),(1,1))$$
I can see why we have this monotonically decreasing relationship from the 1 norm to the infinity norm, and the meaning behind the 1, 2, and infinity norms.  I was wondering if there is any good intuitions or common use cases for the norms other than $p=1,2,\infty$?  They never turned up in my graduate work as concrete things we did anything with, just generic proofs on what would happen if one was bigger than the other.

Comment: One common use case for the $\|\cdot\|_p$ norms with (possibly) $p\notin\{1,2,\infty\}$ is [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality).

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967520/why-are-lp-spaces-for-p-not-1-2-infty-important