# Why we care about Lp spaces?

Tags: lp-spaces

I was reading a [survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.2927) about the LHS technique when it started to talk about Lp- distance in the same distance, where usually $p$ is usually $1$, $2$ or infinite. What are the possible applications of these spaces and their distances/norms?

Comment: Well $L^{2}$ is especially important because it is a Hilbert space but these spaces are so ubiquitous to modern analysis and applied mathematics, that it would be difficult to narrow it down to just a few. Quantum physics, signals and systems, wavelets, mathematical finance, just to name a few all rely on these spaces (especially $L^{2}$).

Comment: And in which applications for LSH could be used? The Hilbert space is the eucledian space with more than 3 dimensions, right?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810029